# ios warning calling init method of a uiviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios, methods, uiviewcontroller, init

I have my custom viewcontroller declared like this:

```
@interface DetailViewControllerSpeciality2 : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
}
```

and I create a new instance like this:

```
DetailViewControllerSpeciality2 *detailViewControllerSpeciality = [[DetailViewControllerSpeciality2 alloc] init];
```

but xcode tell me a warning:

> multiple methods named '-init' found

but I don't have declared a -init method...

Comment: May you post some code? especially the implementation

Comment: what do you need? I've added some methods and modified the viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't showing all the error message, nor the relevant code.  Still, there is enough evidence to make an educated guess.

More likely than not, you have an `init` method declared like:

```
 - (DetailViewControllerSpeciality2 *) init;
```

The compiler is complaining because that conflicts with NSObject's init (that returns `id`).

Declare your `init` to return `id` and the compiler should be happy.  If that isn't the problem, post more code.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
[[DetailViewControllerSpeciality2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```